# VS-Code complains about accessors but targeting ES6

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

I'm running into an odd problem where VS-Code (1.13.1, MacOS) is showing me errors every time I use a class *getter* or *setter* with the error:

> [ts] Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

The problem is my `tsconfig.json` is targeting **ES6**! Here's the config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*-spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Oh and if try running the file via **ts-node** it works without complaining:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run the `TypeScript: Go to project configuration` command in VSCode? Also, can you please share the structure of your project?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? Is it a local npm install or a global install? What version of the language service do you have running in VSCode (bottom right corner)? Errors within the file (red lines) are usually from the language service. Do you have a mismatch? Is your local workspace settings targeting a different version?

Comment: Currently using a locally installed version. The version came from @next and is currently at 2.5.0-dev.20170627

Comment: @MattBierner using the ⌘⌥P menu gives the same configuration as above

Comment: @MichaelSzul just realized maybe I only answered part of your question above ... globally I have version 2.3.4 installed. I am using 2.4.x features and waiting on 2.5 builds for a fix but I could probably fall back to 2.4.x for now

Comment: Yes I can confirm that moving back to `2.4.1` (as locally installed package) has removed this problem. @MichaelSzul do you want to post an "answer" so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: @ken I just asked a bunch of questions; you solved the problem. You should probably post the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the my problem was related to the version of Typescript I was using. Specifically, which *local* version I was using:

[image: local version]

Yes I was living life on the bleeding edge and not surprisingly it led to bleeding. Anyway, I moved back to 2.4.1 (the latest released version as of today) and the error messages went away.

Problem solved. Now I'll just try and be more patient before updating to 2.5.x. :)

Comment: "Yes I was living life on the bleeding edge and not surprisingly it led to bleeding" Well, of course sometimes we merely forget it :) You made my day!